# generate landscape PDF using phantomJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs in asp.net application to convert html to PDF.

First i used this c# code to generate a html page.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Phantomjs/" + HTMLfileName), FileMode.Create))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        sw.Write(GiveBodyText);
    }
}
```

then using phantom command i executed this code.

```
ExecuteCommand(string.Format("cd {0} & phantomjs rasterize.js  {1} {2} \"A4\"", serverPath, HTMLfileName, filename));
```

but the main problem is that i want PDF to be landscape oriented and by default PDFs are portrait and to change that i tried to edit following properties in rasterize.js:

```
page.viewportSize = { width: 1000, height: 600 };

Orientation: 'landscape'
```

but this is not working.